# ¿Cómo puedo sustituir los caracteres alrededor de una palabra o un número?

Tags: javascript, html5, regex

Estoy haciendo un HTML personalizado y tengo que hacer una barra de progreso la cual es así:

```
==[10];=>
```

Quiero reemplazar los corchetes por comillas:

```
=="10";=>
```

pero en una expresión.

Comment: Podrías aclarar tu pregunta, es confuso la idea a la cual quieres llegar

Comment: Y aporta el código que hiciste hasta la fecha

Comment: estas obligado a usar regex?

Answer (score 1):

Hola para logar esto és muy sencillo

Recojes el elemento html donde contiene tu string pongamos elemento.value és tu string, entonces realizas 2 replace

```
elemento.value.replace('[', '"').replace(']','"');
```

Si tienes más de un caracter a reemplazar entonces hay que usar un regular expression:

```
elemento.value.replace(new RegExp('[', 'g'), '"');
```

Comment: tambien recien encontré otra solucion que es data = data.replace(/(\[)|(\])/gm, '"');    donde data es e.innerHTML y e es document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

Comment: Si corercto, esto vendria ser un RegularExpresion que te dice en un replace que si és [ o ] lo reemplaze por "

Comment: y como se hace para que en vez de ser [ o ] sea [ y ]

Comment: Los delimitadores de inicio y fin son `/`, la gm marca que regular expresion és, y si te fijas estan los parentésis para agrupar carácteres y enmedio un `|` para decir o el conjunto de la derecha o el conjunto de la izquierda, no existe un and dado que no és necessario dado que existe el `*` que indica 0 o más caracteres y el `+` que indica uno o más carácteres entre los caracteres buscados, es decir otra forma de escrivir ese regular expresion es `/[+]/gm` pero no te sirve ya que cambiaria todos los carácteres que hay entre `[` y `]`

Comment: aquí mas info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518229/javascript-string-regex-gm-does-not-catch-all-line-at-once